# Empty input : Call to a member function hashName() on null

Tags: laravel, hash, null, submit

I am starting with Laravel ; sorry if the question is really basic but couldn't find an answer yet :

I have a basic form in a view ; the user can choose a picture and upload it. No problem there.
If the user hasn't choosen a picture, there is one by default displayed. No problem there.

But if the user click on the submit button without having choosen anything, there is a "Call to a member function hashName() on null" error message and the function shown to indicate where the problem is is the following, in Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter :

```
public function putFile($path, $file, $options = [])
    {
        $file = is_string($file) ? new File($file) : $file;
        return $this->putFileAs($path, $file, $file->hashName(), $options);
    }
```

*Is there a way to block the error ?*
Modifying the above function maybe ? So that if no image is selected, just clicking on the button wouldn't do anything.

Thks for your help,

Eol111

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function putFile($path, $file, $options = [])
{
    $file = is_string($file) ? new File($file) : null;
    if (!$file) {
        return;
    }
    return $this->putFileAs($path, $file, $file->hashName(), $options);
}
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thanks N69S for your answer. I had to modify it slightly because as it was, it would always return the default image, considering anything not string like null. But changing one line from your code fixed it :

        $file = is_string($file) ? new File($file) : $file;

Comment: @Eol111 there was no way for me to guess your different input so i guessed String only. Having a method that accepts either a string or an instance of the class File is not a good idea, do that where you call the method and accept only an instance of File or only String.